# Transversality condition for functions

Tags: differential-geometry

Mappings $F:R\to M$ and $G:S\to M$ are **transversal** if $F(R)\cap G(S)=\emptyset$ or $F_*(a)T_aR+G_*(b)T_bS=T_pM$ for all $a,b,p$ for which holds $F(a)=G(b)=p$.

How to prove the following:

$F$ is transversal on $G$ iff $F\times G$ is transversal on $i$, where $i:\triangle\to M\times M$ is inclusion of diagonal $\triangle=\{(m,m):m\in M\}$ in $M\times M$.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is clearly local in $R,S,M$, so one can assume that $R=\mathbb{R}^r$, $S=\mathbb{R}^s$, $M=\mathbb{R}^m$ and the relevant points are all origins in the respective vector space (just fix charts in each manifold), so very (very!) informally $a=b=p=0$.

Now the diagonal map is $\mathbb{R}^r\to\mathbb{R}^r\times\mathbb{R}^r$ given by $x\mapsto (x,x)$, so it is linear and the image of the tangent space is exactly the image of the map, i.e. $$\{(x,x): x\in \mathbb{R}^m\}.$$ The sum of the images of the tangent spaces to $a$ and $b$ is $$\{(dF(v),dG(w)):v\in \mathbb{R}^r,w\in\mathbb{R}^s\}.$$

Now their direct sum spans everything if and only if for every $(y,z)$ we can write $$(y,z)=(dF(v)+x,dG(w)+x)$$ for some $v,w,x$, and this is equivalent to saying that for every $u\in \mathbb{R}^m$ we can write $$u=dF(v')+dG(w')$$ for some $v',w'$. I think it is best that you try to prove this last statement yourself.

However, here is a messy (albeit really easy) proof. To go from the first statement to the second, just take $(y,z)=(u,0)$ to get $(u,0)=(dF(v)+x,dG(w)+x)$, so that $u=dF(v)+dG(-w)$ and we may pick $v'=v,w'=-w$. To go from second to first, we can write $y-z=dF(v)-dG(w)$ for some $v,w$, then $(y,z)=(dF(v)-dG(w)+z,dG(w)-dG(w)+z)=(dF(v)+x,dG(w)+x)$ where $x=-dG(w)+z$.